# Why do we use divs inside of divs?

Tags: html

I'm struggling to understand why we use so many divs within divs. For example, why would we use three consecutive divs below one another (`div id="showcase"` then `div class="container"` and then `div class="showcase-content"`) I've seen this in many people's code so what is the advantage of doing this? Doesn't it make more sense to just use the one `div` in the following example. The following HTML is from an online Udemy course:

```
<div id="showcase">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="showcase-content">
      <h1><span class="text-primary">Enjoy</span> Your Stay</h1>
      <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor, 
      eligendi laboriosam. Repellendus officia harum eaque.</p>
      <a class="btn" href="about.html">About Our Hotel</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because it is structured layout.

Comment: Each div is a block element, you can freely combine their padding, margin, shadow, and other unique attributes

Comment: It depends on the kind of layout you want to achieve, and sometimes the CSS/JavaScript framework that may be involved which has certain expectations.

Answer (score 0):

I think it comes down to preference. I personally use many divs because I find myself fighting the predefined behavior of elements rather than them actually helping me.

For example, if I use `<h1>` for a title, 9 times out of 10 I have to adjust the font-size, character spacing, color, margin/padding anyways. To me, I'd rather start fresh and design it to look how I want from the ground up because I know everything that I want with it and how divs respond to those styles.

I don't think there's any advantage/disadvantage to either way, it depends on what you feel you're comfortable with and how you learned it.

If you feel comfortable doing it the way you're showing it there, then have at it!

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to which HTML tags are important.

First of all, HTML is a markup language, that structures the information using tags to give it semantic meaning. A `div` itself has no semantic meaning, so regarding to this the use of nested `div` does not add much, especially if the only child of a `div` is another `div`. So from the HTML perspective, those `div` do not make sense. And they should - if possible - be replaced with more meaningful elements like `section`, `article`, … or give them semantic meaning using ARIA attributes.

The other part is when you want to render the HTML in a browser, here for each tag styling can be applied. If those nested `div` are necessary there is hard to tell without knowing how the elements are styled. In the case of styling, you add elements like `div` or `span` if the elements that have semantic meaning are not sufficient to achieve the desired styling.

If a component library like bootstrap or foundation is used, then there is not much of a choice regarding the nesting structure, as this is given by those libraries. But that does not mean that the `div` elements could not be replaced by something like `section`, as those libraries normally only define by class names and attributes how the nesting has to be.

Answer (score 0):

each div is an element to which different css style is applied and as a css style is applied to a box-model it should be an individual block so its structured that way!!!!